# How to add data dynamically on the right sidebar of my web application depending on the page the user is currently in?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-template

I have developed a web app in angular.js. My question is that I have the menu on left sidebar that remains constant. However, the data on the right sidebar changes depending on the page that the user is currently in. If the user is on home page, then the right sidebar will show, for example, "data 1". If the user is on analytics page, then the right sidebar will show  a graph. I do not know how to implement this using angular in the most optimized way.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use `ng-view` and assign different `controller` for each menu. but without seeing your current angular setup its hard to help you get the correct direction

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the angular routing:

1. Keep the html element as a container (inside to right side bar) provided with a `ng-view` directive
2. You have to create different html template in separate folder, which will be rendered as per the menu selection
3. Write `.config()`, where you write down your specific logic to associate each state/ templateurl to particular controller and template

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, can you give me a live example like codepen/jsfiddle/etc ? Also, I am using ui-router.

Comment: could you please check this, it may help --- http://codepen.io/alexandremasy/pen/mDcEd

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the ngInclude directive. That might be the best way for you to load a template (and the data in your corresponding controller).
L

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngRoute` and call your separate `html template` and `controller`  for each page like this

```
angular
.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.page = 'Data 1';
    }]
  })
  .when('/analytics', {
    templateUrl: 'analytics.html',
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope){
      $scope.page = 'Show Graph';
    }]
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

then add `ng-view` in your html like this

```
<div class="content">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

working demo [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nw99775kwaSS3nYALzWp?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Actually, this is not what I asked for. I am using ui-router and already have a view component. Inside that view component, I want another view component which should be loaded on the right sidebar as per the page.